# How to stop visual studio 2022 from referencing .NETFramework, version=4.0? Because latest version of VS 2022 doesn't support .NET earlier than 4.5

Tags: python, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

I am making a simple Python command-line application.I also tried to change from the application tab of project but the problem is the "application tab" doesnt exist(shown in screenshot below).
I just want it to reference to the latest version of .net. How do i fix it?

```
[Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks  PythonApplication6  R:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   1217    
]
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO0so.png)
[no application tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKjsy.png)

Comment: Why the python tag?

Comment: its a simple command line application that im making in python...

Comment: also its shown in the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Given the timeframe of your original post, I believe it is a defect reported here: https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/issues/6882

It has been marked as fixed that has since been fixed and should be in the next release of Visual Studio 2022.

The workaround is to target a newer framework (given in the following link https://github.com/microsoft/PTVS/issues/6747)

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
     <TargetFrameworkMoniker>.NETFramework,Version=$(TargetFrameworkVersion)</TargetFrameworkMoniker>
</PropertyGroup>
```